# Remove a String Located between Character

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have an email column in my table. How to update email column with removing string between underscore `_` and `@`.

Example:

Input: `andri_pasardigital@zcode.id`  
Output: `andri@zcode.id`

Comment: Use `_\w+` and replace it with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this : `_(.*)@`

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9SM51Y/1)

Comment: Your answer should include code to show how to do that in SQL with Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex, but API: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Something along the lines of

```
create table T (id serial primary key, email text);    
insert into T (email) values ('bal_hussa@palo.enf' )
```

with

```
select substring( email from 1 for position('_' in email)-1) || 
       substring( email from position('@' in email))
from T
```

produces

```
bal@palo.enf
```

could also work to answer **Remove a String Located between Character**